# ArchLinux on netbook

Tags: netbook, linux-distributions, arch-linux

I am planning to get a netbook ([ACER Aspire one 522](http://www.acer.co.uk/ac/en/GB/content/series/aspireone522)). Will ArchLinux work well in a netbook. I am looking for a light weight Linux distribution on netbook.

Update: I installed ArchLinux on my netbook. It works great!! Yet to setup wifi, i will update if there are any problems.

Comment: Should check out the [Arch Wiki Page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Acer_Aspire_One) on Aspire Ones, although outdated but useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually Arch's simplicity is a good choice for netbooks' handicapped processors.

However if your netbook carries a broadcom BCM4313 wifi nic ( `$lspci` to check it out ), there may be compatibility issue that I haven't get over with my notebook ( the very model AO522 ). Afain, no worry if your notebook uses a atheros one.

https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/26847

Comment: I did not have any major issue with wifi. I had to blacklist a module, thats all. It worked otherwise.

Comment: Haven't got over it myself though. wlan0 won't come out if I blacklist those modules. But it is glad to know that bug is assigned.

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Can i use the same installer iso image for x86 available? or is there a netbook version available?

Comment: Yes, it is the same image. There is no such thing as a "netbook version"

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It will work. I have hp mini netbook and arch works on it. 
But arch does not come with gui. You have to install the X server, video drivers, synaptics driver for touchpad, a desktop environment. Follow this guide 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide

Answer (score 0):

I  have a ACER Aspire myself and I can guarantee it's all right.

Generally every notebook is fine with Linux. There are also videos on YouTube, that tell you how to upgrade your notebook. I only know about some issues with QubesOS, but that's all. I recommend the Archlinux wiki about everything in Linux.